# Как проверить что все элементы подмассива принадлежат одному типу в js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как проверить что все элементы подмассива принадлежат одному типу в js.

```
[['', 'qwerty'], [65, 98, 13], [''], ['', '1'], ['', 1], []]
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
const arrs = [['', 'qwerty'], [65, 98, 13], [''], ['', '1'], ['', 1], []]

const res = arrs.map((item) => {
  if (item.length < 2) return true
  const [first, ...items] = item
  return items.every((i) => typeof i === typeof first)
})

console.log(res)
```

UPD: для скорости на больших массивах лучше так

```js
const res3 = arrs.map((item) => {
  for (let i = 1; i < item.length; ++i)  if (typeof item[0] !== typeof item[i]) return false
  return true
})
```

Comment: черт, это круто))

Answer (score 1):

Предыдущий ответ верен, но слегка переусложнен - поэтому, вот то же самое решение в более простом (учебном) варианте:

```js
const arrs = [['', 'qwerty'], [65, 98, 13], [''], ['', '1'], ['', 1], []];

const res = arrs.map(([firstItem, ...restItems]) => (
  restItems.every(item => typeof item === typeof firstItem)
));

console.log(res);
```

Когда метод `every` вызван от пустого массива, он возвращает `true` - такое поведение и логично, и закреплено стандартом ES. Поэтому, здесь не обязательна предварительная проверка количества элементов, без нее результат тоже будет корректным (существует общее правило: дублирований стандартного поведения своим кодом лучше избегать, по мере возможности).

Comment: Разница в [производительности копирования](https://jsben.ch/3JaL6), когда Spread syntax извлекает несуществующие элементы. А по хорошему здесь нужен старый/добрый for без всяких копирований.

Comment: @Alexander, тут нет spread (`...` в данном случае является rest-оператором, у него противоположное действие), а разница в производительности обусловлена накладными расходами на вызов метода - конечно, в реальных задачах _иногда_ имеет смысл избегать "лишних" вызовов, но достигается это уже не такой проверкой. А в учебном примере, где оптимизации это далеко не самое важное, такая проверка только смущает (затрудняет понимание, и учит плохой практике "велосипедостроения": разница в ~12% на тысяче повторений этого не оправдывает, имхо).

Comment: Я ошибся с формулировкой, конечно я говорил о "Деструктурирующем присваивании" - `[a, ...b] = []`

Comment: @Alexander, верно, тут есть деструктуризация, но вряд ли потери быстродействия на ней (утверждать трудно, т.к. это уже специфика реализации JS-движка: где-то будет медленно, где-то будет быстро). И должен пояснить, что этот ответ в первую очередь не критикует первоначальный, а показывает более простую форму того же самого решения. Она чисто учебная, и следует логике "оптимизации == иногда хорошо; но реализовывать то что уже корректно реализовано == всегда плохо" (даже если велосипед дает несколько мс, он остается велосипедом... есть мнение что новичкам лучше избегать таких практик).

Comment: [Более корректное сравнение производительности синт.тестом](https://jsben.ch/sEVLB) оригинального и упрощенного вариантов (спойлеры: изначально предполагаемых потерь на вызове метода - по факту не наблюдается, как минимум в хромиуме под андроид).

Comment: Как бы не писались тесты, на "коротких" массивах это не имеет особого смысла. Добавь чуть элементов и обычный `for` [побеждает оба наших примера](https://jsben.ch/NMERJ).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128361/discussion-between-yar85-and-alexander-lonberg).

Comment: У меня там [отображается такое](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Unar/z5S8Arisi), а учетку надо искать, но точно не ночью.